# My VBA code won't place userform inputs into cells

Tags: excel, vba

This is going to seem like a stupid question but I'm trying to get some information entered into a userform to be placed into a cell on my worksheet in a database. Everything is inputting correctly apart from 4 lines. Could someone please enlighten me as to why this is the case? I'm probably missing something really stupid here but I can't find it for the life of me.
Below is my code:

```
 Dim Initialrow As Variant

 Initialrow = Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 0)

If IsEmpty(Initialrow) = True Then
    Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 0).Value = InitialUF.VisitDate.Value
    Sheets("Jan").Range("RP_Start").Offset(1, 0) = InitialUF.RPName  '<-- This isn't executing'
    Sheets("Jan").Range("Proj_Start").Offset(1, 0) = InitialUF.Project ' <-- This isn't executing'
    Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 3) = Observation
    Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 4) = Comment
    Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 5) = Improvement

    If Len(Improvement) > Len(Comment) Then
       Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 5).Rows.AutoFit
    ElseIf Len(Comment) > Len(Improvement) Then
       Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 4).Rows.AutoFit
    ElseIf Comment = Null Then
       Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 5).Rows.AutoFit
    ElseIf Improvement = Null Then
       Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 4).Rows.AutoFit
    ElseIf Len(Comment) = Len(Improvement) Then
       Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 4).Rows.AutoFit
    Else
    End If
Else
    Sheets("Jan").Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = InitialUF.VisitDate.Value
    Sheets("Jan").Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = InitialUF.RPName '<-- This isn't executing'
    Sheets("Jan").Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = InitialUF.Project '<-- This isn't executing'
    Sheets("Jan").Range("Obs_Start").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Observation
    Sheets("Jan").Range("Obs_Start").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1) = Comment
    Sheets("Jan").Range("Obs_Start").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2) = Improvement

    If Len(Improvement) > Len(Comment) Then
        Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 5).Rows.AutoFit
    ElseIf Len(Comment) > Len(Improvement) Then
        Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 4).Rows.AutoFit
    ElseIf Comment = Null Then
        Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 5).Rows.AutoFit
    ElseIf Improvement = Null Then
        Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 4).Rows.AutoFit
    ElseIf Len(Comment) = Len(Improvement) Then
        Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").Offset(1, 4).Rows.AutoFit
    Else
    End If
End If
```

`RPName` and `Project` are both the names of the textboxes in the `InitialUF` userform. This code is executed in the subsequent UF. I copied and pasted those lines from a button on `InitialUF`, where they were inputting correctly, but refuse to work now.
Thanks for your time and thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: `This isn't executing` - what is it doing instead?

Comment: So the cells that I want to be populated with that information are just left blank

Comment: What is `Initialrow`? Did you step through the code to check if it even reaches that line?

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to copy that line into the question. And yep it does get to that point. I'm so stumped rn

Comment: That means the `InitialUF.RPName` and `InitialUF.Project` are blank. How are you transitioning between the forms?

Comment: I've figured it out! Thanks guys for helping me work through it. GSerg, when you asked me how I'm transitioning between forms, I completely forgot that when I continued from InitialUF, my code Unloaded InitialUF, which meant that RPName and Project held no value in the next UF. I fixed it by Unloading initialUF at a later stage. Thank you so much!